# Way to save edittext box data in the xml code itself?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Is there a way of saving data users have entered in an EditText box in the xml itself? I don't want to have to write Java code to have to grab the entered data and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by going a different route to my whole application design. I think it's out of scope for this question though and is too suited to my particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

XML layout files in android are just for setting up the layout of the activity. You cannot modify these files by code or save new information to them during runtime. For what you are looking to do you will need to write some code. I suggest using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save and load previously entered data. You could do this in the onResume and onPause callbacks to avoid having an actual save button or anything like that.

Comment: You could also attach something to the 'addTextChangedListener' of the EditText.  Write a method that gets called in your onCreate.  It will check SharedPrefs to see if this field should have a value from previous runs, and also add a TextWatcher that will save all updates in SharedPrefs when the user types.

Comment: I think I phrased my question in a bad way.
I mean instead of grabbing the entered data from the EditText using Java, is there any way I can specify where I want the entered data to be saved in the XML file?

Comment: So are you asking if there is an equivalent of the onClick xml attribute but for EditText to save and load data? If that is what you are asking I'm sorry to say I don't think anything like that exists.

Comment: @Bobbake4 I had a look into implementing the onClick xml attribute for example a save button, and it still requires me having to write code..

Comment: I solved this by going a different route to my whole application design. I think it's out of scope for this question though and is too suited to my particular problem.